# Sticky footer leads to overflow

Tags: html, css

i'm making a site and I want the footer to be always at the end of the page (not fixed) but I'm having trouble. Works great:

[image]

but when I shrink down the vieport the content "gets out" of the page and the footer gets messed up:

[image]

If someone could help me I'll be grateful!
This is the link:

http://myrtabaiter.com/site/alfareria.htm

PS: I DON'T ADD CODE BECAUSE IT WILL MAKE IT CONFUSING SINCE I'TS A LITTLE TRICKY THE WAY I USED TO SET THE BACKGROUND

Comment: 1) How do you plan solving the problem without adding code? 
2) Can you please provide some code so we don't need to figure out css from the console

Comment: Nothing is too tricky for the Stack Overflow community. Please post relevant code. :)

Comment: I plan to solve it using jQuery and getting the height of the document, then, if the height of it is higher than the background height i'll set the background height to be the height of the document.

Comment: Also, do you need to support legacy IE browsers (8 and/or 9)? Is the footer a static or dynamic height? These have bearing on the best approach.

Comment: The height has a static height, just support for ie9 and so on

Comment: Whoa. That may be over-engineering the solution. There are CSS only ways of accomplishing this that are much simpler.

Comment: When I set `<footer>` to `position: fixed` it appeared to work just fine. Try it and work on the content area height.

Comment: yes, that works but I don't want that because if the screen is to short the fixed footer overlays the page content

Comment: I figured out what caused this, first I set min-height: 100% to the background not height and then I added a div to clear the float of the elements when you opened a photo, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

### CSS-only sticky footer by Ryan Fait

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

Source: [Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)